# References to IDs in APIs responses, null or 0?

Tags: api, architecture, backend, software-design

I consider myself that 0 is not a good thing to do when returning information from an API

e.g.

```
{
    userId: int|null
}
```

I have a colleague that insists in that `userId` should be 0 or -1, but that forces a system to know that the 0 means "not set", instead of `null` which is universally known as `not set`.

The same happens with `string` params, like `logoUrl`. However, in this case I think it is acceptable to have an empty string instead of null if the variable is not set or was unset.

Is there bibliography, standards, etc, that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any standard around that, but the way I take those kind of decisions is by thinking about the way consumer services would read this response, the goal being to provide a very smooth and clean consuming workflow. This exercise can even be transformed into a documentation for your API consumers.

In your case, instead of returning a null/0 field, I would simply remove that field altogether when it's empty and let the consumers explicitly mark that field as optional in the model they use to deserialize this response.

In that way, they'll explicitly have to deal with those optional fields, than relying on the API to always provide a value for them.

---